Can I replace drum brakes with disc brakes?
I have a Honda Civic with drum brakes that are giving me trouble. I'm considering switching to disc brakes, but I know it involves a lot of upgrades and modifications. Is it a good idea by doing so, or will it affect my car functions by changing its default setup?

What is the year of your Civic?

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I have Honda Civic LX (2016) model.

As with most things automotive, if you can dream it, it can happen. The only things needed are money, talent, and time. So, yes, doing what you're suggesting is definitely possible.
Here's the rub, though. In order to do this, you've got a lot of stuff to change out. Besides the obvious, like replacing the wheel cylinders with calipers, and shoes with pads, you also have to change out the hubs, hardware, and brake lines. Depending on how the spindles are done, those will have to be changed out as well. Then you have things like changing out the emergency braking mechanism. Most drum brakes pull double duty in this regard, while some disk brakes do, but others have separate shoes which provide the e-brake. Also, the ABS will be affected, but is most likely tied to the hubs. Rewiring may be required.
There are two ways you can accomplish this. The first is by sourcing all of the replacement parts needed. This is a lot more complicated than going to your local parts store, as they are going to look at you as though you're an alien. They carry the pads, calipers, and brake lines, and would have to order the spindles/hubs, but all the other little bits/pieces would probably need to come from a Honda parts counter, which is expensive.
The other way to accomplish what you are thinking about is to get a donor car, or go to a pull-it-yourself wrecking yard and get everything you need. That way you can get all of the parts in one fell swoop. This would probably be quite a bit cheaper as well.
Whichever method you use, replacement would most likely be straight forward. Honda, like most car manufacturers, don't make it overly difficult to change between the two. All of the bolt up locations and such should be the same between the two.
All this said, it's probably much easier and cheaper to just figure out what's going on with your current setup and get it fixed. The rear brakes on most vehicle only provide about 35% of the braking power. The front ones do most of the work. Having shoes/drums in the rear is well more than enough stopping power for the job it needs to do.

Thanks for you help.

@VainDieselJr - If this answers your question, please use the check mark to indicate it as the answer.

Converting drum brakes to disc brakes on your Honda Civic can be a good upgrade, offering better braking performance.
Recommendation:
Consult a certified mechanic.
They can assess your drum brakes, determine if your Civic is compatible with a disc conversion, and discuss the costs and benefits of both options.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! We appreciate you being here and attempting to answer the question. While technically your answer isn't wrong, it doesn't provide the OP much information. When someone asks a question, they inherently know they could go to a mechanic for a solution. They ask their question here to get the needed information to make informed decisions, mainly on whether this is something they can do themselves. Telling them to go to a mechanic isn't really what they are looking for in an answer.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 This answer reeks of ChatGPT.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@MTA - I'd tend to disagree with you in this case, mainly because there's not enough information. A ChatGPT answer is (in my experience) usually quite verbose, with too much information. I couldn't tell you one way or the other, and you may have a lot more experience as such.

GPT or not, either way it's an utter non-answer (flagged as such) and given the profile is basically an advert for their car maintenance blog it might even cross into spam territory

@motosubatsu whom are you talking about ?

@VainDieselJr The answerer, not yourself :)

@motosubatsu Sorry for the misunderstanding
